# Why does property return undefined instead of object?

Tags: javascript

In first alert(this.child) returns an object, second it returns undefined whereas I would expect same result. Why and how to fix it ?

https://jsfiddle.net/7jnyozx1/2/

```
    var Child = (function() {
  function Child(data) {
  }

  return Child;
})();

var ChildModel = (function() {
  function ChildModel(data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.child = new Child(data);
    alert(this.child); // TEST OK : object
  }

  function local() {
    alert(this.child); // TEST KO : undefined
  }

  ChildModel.prototype.call = function() {
    local();
  }

  return ChildModel;
})();

data = "hello";
var childModel = new ChildModel(data);
childModel.call();
```

Comment: @Sukima: Only that there is no `Object.prototype.call`. Nothing is wrong with `.call` methods.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe I was thinking `Function.call` opps.

Answer (score 2):

Because the function `local` is in no way related to the object. You could put that function at the top of your file and it would work in the exact same way.

You could do `local.apply(this);` to pass the `this` from the `call` method to the function, but you might as well make `local` a prototype function as well.

Comment: It's cases like this that make me _squee_ for es2015 classes and Object literal function syntax!

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside of local is scoped to the global object (window). In order to make the local function scoped to your expected this binding (coming from ChildModel) you would need to pass the this binding in from the prototype call.

```
ChildModel.prototype.call = function() {
    local.call(this);
}
```